# ajax doesn't check email availability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to check email availability, but something is wrong here. Inside a form I have:

```
<input id="inpMail" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inpMail").change(function() { 
        var mail = $("#inpMail").val();
        var msgbox = $("#status");  //`status` is a div

        if (mail.length > 4) {
            $("#status").html('<img src="img/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');  //this works

            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ajax.php",  // this file is in the same folder
                data: "mail="+ mail,  
                success: function(msg) {  
                    $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 
                        if (msg == 'OK') { 
                            msgbox.html('<img src="img/available.png" align="absmiddle">');  //doesn't work
                        }  
                        else {  
                            msgbox.html(msg);  // doesn't work
                        }  
                    });
                } 
            }); 
        }
        else {
            $("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please enter atleast 5 letters</font>');  //this works
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Database not connected");  // this message never appears
$db = mysql_select_db("vedic", $conn) or die("Database not connected"); 

if (isset($_POST['inpMail']))
{
    $mail = $_POST['inpMail'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select id from members where email='$mail'"); 
    // my db is named `vedic`, table is `members` some fields are `id` and `email`  

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql))
    {
        echo '<STRONG>'.$mail.'</STRONG> is already in use.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think unnecessary;
**$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){**

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: you need to correct so many things..

Comment: @DipeshParmar I shudder at the thought of that SQL query open to sql injection.
SunSky Perhpas you could create a jsfiddle with just the JS bits? I take it you have used your browser's console to see that your PHP code is working correctly?

Comment: the mysql_ functions really shouldn't be used in new code.. it would be worth your while migrating to mysqli or, even better, the PDO equivalents

Comment: @msturdy Good point as they're now depreciated in 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your javascript with code below,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#inpMail").change(function() 
    { 
        var mail = $(this).val();
        var msgbox = $("#status");  //`status` is a div

        if(mail.length > 4)
        {
            msgbox.html('<img src="img/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');  //this works

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ajax.php",  // this file is in the same folder
                data: "mail="+ mail,  
                success: function(msg)
                {  
                    if(msg == 'OK')
                    { 
                        msgbox.html('<img src="img/available.png" align="absmiddle">');  //doesn't work
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        msgbox.html(msg);  // doesn't work
                    }  
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Please enter atleast 5 letters</font>');  //this works
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

You have extra `});` at the end, Also you were repeating yourself with same selector which was defined globally.

**PHP**

You are sending `mail` params as posted `email address` and you are checking for `inpMail` which will not return true ever.

IN php replace

```
if (isset($_POST['inpMail']))
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['mail']))
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add the `ajaxComplete` handler in the `success` callback as it has already happened. Try this:

```
success: function(msg) {  
    if (msg == 'OK') { 
        msgbox.html('<img src="img/available.png" align="absmiddle">');
    }  
    else {  
        msgbox.html(msg);
    }  
}
```

Also your PHP code is wide open to injection attacks. Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: what about `data: "mail="+ mail,` passed params....and `inpMail` checking in php...

Comment: `"mail=" + mail` is fine, although you're right `inpMail` in PHP should be renamed to `mail`.